# Compare column value against list of regex values stored in another table and update accordingly

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

<sup>I am new to Oracle programming.</sup>
I want to check the "msg" value of "Table1" against the "regex" values from "Table2".
If the regular expression matches as such, I want to update the respective "regex_id" in "Table1".

Usual query: `SELECT 'match found' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('s 27', '^(s27|s 27)')`

**Table1**

```
MSG      REG_EXID
Ss27        ?
s27         ?
s28         ?
s29         ?
```

**Table2**

```
REGEX       REG_EXID  RELEVANCE
^(s27|s 27)        1  10
^(s29|s 29)        2  2
^(m28|m 28)        3  2
^(s27|s 27)        4  100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the newly added "relevance" into account, with Oracle 11g you could try along

```
UPDATE Table1 T1
SET T1.reg_exID = 
  (SELECT DISTINCT
  MAX(reg_exID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY relevance DESC) OVER (PARTITION BY regex)
  FROM Table2
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(T1.msg, regex)
  )
;
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b89c/16/1).

Comment: Thank you very much for solution, i dint not understand       DENSE_RANK FIRST, i will read :).

Answer (score 1):

You could work along

```
UPDATE Table1
SET reg_exID = (SELECT reg_exID FROM Table2 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Table1.msg, regex));
```

Please keep in mind:

- None of your current sample records will be updated as REGEX are case sensitive.
- The above `UPDATE` will fail, if more than a single REGEX does match.
- You could rewrite the current REGEX expressions along "^m ?28".

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca6bb/3/2) (With some data added to actually show the effect.)

Please comment if and as clarification/adjustment is required.

Comment: The above scenario will work only if we have single entry for regex
If we have multiple reg ex and based on high relevance i have to pick how it is possible.

Comment: Not sure, what you are after. Could you, please, re-phrase and/or provide an example? - Just seeing, you edited the question. Would it make sense to return this one to the previous state and to file a new request?

Comment: sorry but in the above scenario if i have same regex configured by some reason, update will not work. that why i updated relevance in question.
below query will solve my problem , but i want to run this with update , where i m getting error like TABLE1"."MSG": invalid identifier
select reg_exid from (select reg_exID from   Table2   where REGEXP_LIKE('s27', regex)   order by relvance desc) where rownum =1;

Comment: OK - I see, what you are after. Do you need just a working solution - or does that have performance implications?

Comment: thank you , you understood the concern , well i can say , i am implementing this solution because it is more effective and performance is good.
because all these operations were done in java which i felt time consuming and heavy process on java and database also.
let us check the solution available , i will try to check performance hit later, i m going to deal with
500K entries will be updated with this update query in Table1 , Table2 will have close 50K-100K records max.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running?